# Java: How to implement finding a word from 2D array (word search)?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, depth-first-search, trie

Given a 2D board and a list of words from the dictionary, I would like to find all words in the board.

Each word must be constructed from letters of sequentially adjacent cell, where "adjacent" cells are those horizontally or vertically neighboring. The same letter cell may not be used more than once in a word.

For example, given `words = ["oath","pea","eat","rain"]` and board =

```
[
  ['o','a','a','n'],
  ['e','t','a','e'],
  ['i','h','k','r'],
  ['i','f','l','v']
]

Return ["eat","oath"].
```

And came across the following implementation:

```
public List<String> findWords(char[][] board, String[] words) {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    TrieNode root = buildTrie(words);
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
            dfs (board, i, j, root, res);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public void dfs(char[][] board, int i, int j, TrieNode p, List<String> res) {
    char c = board[i][j];
    if (c == '#' || p.next[c - 'a'] == null) return;
    p = p.next[c - 'a'];
    if (p.word != null) {   // found one
        res.add(p.word);
        p.word = null;     // de-duplicate
    }

    board[i][j] = '#';
    if (i > 0) dfs(board, i - 1, j ,p, res); 
    if (j > 0) dfs(board, i, j - 1, p, res);
    if (i < board.length - 1) dfs(board, i + 1, j, p, res); 
    if (j < board[0].length - 1) dfs(board, i, j + 1, p, res); 
    board[i][j] = c;
}

public TrieNode buildTrie(String[] words) {
    TrieNode root = new TrieNode();
    for (String w : words) {
        TrieNode p = root;
        for (char c : w.toCharArray()) {
            int i = c - 'a';
            if (p.next[i] == null) p.next[i] = new TrieNode();
            p = p.next[i];
       }
       p.word = w;
    }
    return root;
}

class TrieNode {
    TrieNode[] next = new TrieNode[26];
    String word;
}
```

And in `buildTrie(String[] words)`, after setting up the trie for a particular word, it does `p.word = w;`. And in `dfs(...)`, it checks for `if (p.word != null)`.

But how is it that the `p.word` is `null` until the very last of the character in a word has been found, then `p.word` is not `null` anymore?

`p.word` is not dependent on any indexes and it is directly related to the object itself, so should be able to be accessed at any point, but I just do not understand how it is `null` until the very last character of the word has been found.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample trie:

[image]

Considering the above trie, during constructing the trie, the `word` is `null` by default for every node except in the node where it ends.

For exaple, on inserting `buy` in the above trie, we scan every characters of word `buy` and put it per one node. And when we reaches the last character `y`, we put `buy` into `word` variable of that node. That's why you will find every other node's `word` equal to `null` except the node where it ends.

Comment: Thank you so much once again! Is there a way to have a quick chat with you? Would like to get some clarification on some dynamic programming and whatnot.